# How to get real maps and sets in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, data-structures

Javascript is a neat language, but seems to lack some very basic facilities like maps and sets.

A **Map** is a key/value store where the keys and values can be arbitrary objects, and there is at most one value for each key, distinguished by strict equality.

A **Set** is the same as a map, except it has no values and you're only interested in existence, again by strict equality.

If I want to use these ADTs, the closest we have in javascript is the Object, which is almost right, but coerces all keys to string, which makes it useless for some things that real sets and maps would be used for.

Given maps, sets are trivial: `set[key] = true` instead of `set[key] = value`. Or one could implement the full set functionality (for small sets) with Arrays, Array.indexOf, and Array.splice. Adding a parallel values list would give map functionality. For larger data sets, one could implement a hash table on top of plain objects, but I imagine this would become a more serious project.

So my question is, is there a more idiomatic implementation, (or a simpler solution,) to get full Map/Set functionality out of Javascript than the above suggestions? Or does everyone just bite the bullet on this?

**EDIT** So it looks like the [es6 maps/sets spec](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3asimple_maps_and_sets) is the way to go. I'll accept an answer linking to/showing a simple and usable shim.

Comment: FYI, those two datastructures are coming to JavaScript [with ECMAScript 6](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:simple_maps_and_sets) and an experimental implementation is [already available in Firefox and Chrome](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim/. Given that maps and sets come with their own API in ES6, they are shimable, even if you (presumably) won't get the same performance as the native implementation.

Comment: Implementing a HashMap is not that hard. I implemented the  Java version in Javascript. It works just fine.

Comment: @IngoBürk: Wrong; you cannot get a referential hashcode of an arbitrary object.  (unless you mutate it)

Comment: @SLaks there is: 0. It's a stupid hash, but perfectly legal according to the hash code contract

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do this in Javascript.

## [*Yet*](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:simple_maps_and_sets).

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be a more idiomatic solution than biting the bullet with the suggestions in OP. However, as the other contributors have noted, Maps and Sets are coming up in ES6, and there is an [executable specification](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3asimple_maps_and_sets).

The ES6 executable specification uses the map implementation suggesting in OP, and implements sets in terms of that; Maps are done as a keys array and a vals array maintained in parallel with Array.splice and linear scanning. Unfortunately, it seems to use some esoteric syntax that is not acceptable in mainstream JS.

To get us a usable shim for this, I snarfed the linked spec, converted it to coffeescript with a few modifications, and wrote some tests to demonstrate functionality. The code is [on my github](https://github.com/wwt/mapsetjs):

```
#A non-stupid alternative to Array.prototype.indexOf
indexOfIdentical = (keys, key) ->
    for i of keys
        if keys[i] == key
            return i
    return -1

class Map
    constructor: (a = []) ->
        @keys = [];
        @vals = [];
        for [k,v] in a
            @set k, v

    get: (key) ->
        i = indexOfIdentical @keys, key
        return if i < 0 then undefined else @vals[i]

    has: (key) ->
        return 0 <= indexOfIdentical @keys, key

    set: (key, val) ->
        i = indexOfIdentical @keys, key
        if i < 0
            i = @keys.length
        @keys[i] = key
        @vals[i] = val

    del: (key) ->
        i = indexOfIdentical @keys, key
        if i < 0
            return false
        @keys.splice i, 1
        @vals.splice i, 1
        return true

class Set
    constructor: (a = []) ->
        @keys = []
        for key in a
            @add key

    has: (key) ->
        return 0 <= indexOfIdentical @keys, key

    add: (key) ->
        i = indexOfIdentical @keys, key
        if i < 0
            i = @keys.length
        @keys[i] = key

    del: (key) ->
        i = indexOfIdentical @keys, key
        if i < 0
            return false
        @keys.splice i, 1
        return true

#this is implemented as a simple node.js module:
#include with mapset = require("./path/to/mapset.js")
module.exports = {Map: Map, Set: Set}
```

Answer (score 0):

*No, there is not.* But Javascript Objects are the closest representation to both sets and maps that you are going to get.

The following are different ways they can be used:

```
var foo = {]

// The following two are the same thing.
foo.bar = true; 
foo['bar'] = true; 

var bar = 'bar';
foo[bar] = true; // again, the same thing.
```

or

```
var foo = { bar: true }
```

They can be easily iterated:

```
for (item in foo) {
  if (foo.hasOwnProperty[item]) {
    console.log(item); // --> returns 'bar';
    console.log(foo[item]); // --> returns true;
  }
}
```

To check existence of a property:

```
if (foo[bar] !== undefined) {
  // ... it doesn't
}

// If one declares a property without any value,
foo.bar;

//It will still come out as undefined
console.log(foo.bar); // --> undefined
```

Comment: That's exactly what he said in the question.  Read more carefully.

Comment: Objects are specifically addressed and rejected by the question. As was pointed out in the comments to my (now deleted) answer, they're unsuitable as their property names are all coerced to strings.

Comment: ... And the keys can't be arbitrary.